# How to write a text document in new tab / window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Below code is used to display the image in new tab if the extension is jpg.

Similarly, I want to write a text document *(from base64 string to text)* in new tab if the extension is txt.

```
success: function (data) {
            var extension = fileName.split('.').pop();
            if (extension == "jpg") {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.d;
                var w = window.open("");
                w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
            }
            else if(extension == "txt") {

            }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write content to another browser window using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169833/how-do-i-write-content-to-another-browser-window-using-javascript)

Comment: @Sadikhasan, That question not mentioned about the conversion of base64 string to text

Comment: @JohnStephen what is not working? there is no code in your else if condition.

Comment: How to convert the base64 string to txt format?

Comment: You don't give enough context in your question, a full working example which includes how the file is read by the browser and processed would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 images are more trivial because you just have to stick the base64 into the image source, other things like text need to be decoded. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

```
success: function (data) {
            var extension = fileName.split('.').pop();
            if (extension == "jpg") {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data.d;
                var w = window.open("");
                w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
            }
            else if(extension == "txt") {
                var w = window.open("");
                w.document.write(window.atob(data.d));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Exactly the answer I need.