# document.write within a new open.document

Tags: javascript, window.open

I was wondering if it is possible to have a new window.open (It will be the child window) nested into the document.write of the parent window of `myWin.window.open`?

```
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick="window.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=200,width=400,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent');">Click Here to Access the Movie Window</a> <br><br>");
```

here is the full codes, if this helps better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var myWin = window.open("", "", "height=500,width=680,resizable=yes,top=100,left=400");
    myWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Guardian Of the Galaxy<\/title>');
    myWin.document.write('<style type="text\/css">');
    myWin.document.write('<!-- ');
    myWin.document.write('body#lab8img {background-image: url("Labs_Images/GofG.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;} ');
    myWin.document.write('p {color:#fff;font-size:20px;} ');
    myWin.document.write('h1 {color:#fff;font-size:24px;} ');
    myWin.document.write('a {color:#000;font-weight:bold; line-height:0.5; width:100%; text-decoration:none;} ');
    myWin.document.write('a hover {color:#2B65EC;font-weight:bold; line-height:0.5; padding:15px;} ');
    myWin.document.write('div#box {background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); border: 2px solid black; margin: 30px;height: 27%; width:90%;} ');
    myWin.document.write('--><\/style>');
    myWin.document.write('<\/head><body id="lab8img" onload="setImageSize();">');
    myWin.document.write('<\/body>');
    myWin.document.write('<\/html>');
    myWin.document.close();
    myWin.document.write("<div style='text-align:center; '><h1>What about the Movie?</h1></div> <br>");
    myWin.document.write("<div style='text-align:left; padding:0px 8px 0px 8px;'><p>Guardians of the Galaxy is a 2014 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the tenth installment in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. </p></div><br>");
    myWin.document.write("<div Id='box' style='text-align:center;");


    myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick="window.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=200,width=400,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent');">Click Here to Access the Movie Window</a> <br><br>");
    myWin.document.write("</div>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write content to another browser window using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169833/how-do-i-write-content-to-another-browser-window-using-javascript)

Comment: @Sow Does `js` at Question not return expected results ?

Comment: @EricPhillips I look at the other answer, and it is different. I want to have the child window.open opens as a link into the parent window via the document.write. After, you click on it, and it opens the child window.

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean?

Comment: @Sow Tried `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry I'm not understanding..?what do you mean by js at question?

Comment: @Sow Have you tried `javascript` posted at Question ?

Comment: @Sow What is result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works fine. There is nothing inherently problematic with using javascript to generate a popup window with a link to generate another popup window.

The issue is a small syntax error: you are not escaping your double-quotes on the line where you are writing the `a` tag, so it breaks because your string is not what you expect it to be

```
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick="window.open('...
```

You are opening your string with double quotes `("<a href...)` but then you use double quotes again in the onclick event (`onclick="window.open(...`) so just escape the double quotes in the onclick event (note the back slashes)

```
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=200,width=400,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent');\">Click Here to Access the Movie Window</a> <br><br>");
```

Also of course note that the code will also break if you have popups blocked, because `myWin` won't get assigned the new window if popups are blocked.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you need to add \..?